# Error with dhash.get_num_bits_different

Tags: python, string, hash, bitwise-operators

I was following this [library "dhash"](http://tech.jetsetter.com/2017/03/21/duplicate-image-detection/), 
but get error when using its `dhash.get_num_bits_different`:

```
def get_num_bits_different(hash1, hash2):
    return bin(hash1 ^ hash2).count('1')

hash1 = '3d77xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
hash2 = '9301xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

get_num_bits_different(hash1, hash2)
>>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to an int like:

```
get_num_bits_different(int(hash1, 16), int(hash2, 16))
```

#### Test Code:

```
def get_num_bits_different(hash1, hash2):
    return bin(hash1 ^ hash2).count('1')

hash1 = '3d77'
hash2 = '9301'

print(get_num_bits_different(int(hash1, 16), int(hash2, 16)))
```

#### Results:

```
10
```